# Find if an array of objects includes an attribute with a specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code works, but can you tell me if this is the right way to do it?

I have an array of Position objects and I want to check if it contains an object which attribute 'hidden' has "false' value:

```
<% if positions.collect{|position| position.hidden}.include?(false) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you like, another way to simplify this is: `if positions.map(&:hidden).include?(false)`. (Warning: this and the original approach will behave differently from the answers given below if the 'hidden' attribute ever returns nil.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<% if positions.any?{|position| !position.hidden} %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Using the [any?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001500) method

Answer (score 5):

`if positions.any? {|position| not position.hidden}`

Answer (score 1):

you can also use [all?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all?) method:

```
<% unless positions.all? {|position| position.hidden} %>
 ...
<% end %>
```